# Getting an list which contains specific text using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get the list of "ul" which contains the term "[My search Text]" inside it.

I have tried using the below regex but its not returning me the proper output,

```
<ul[^>]*>\s*?\w+?(.|\n).*(\[My search Text\]).*(.|\n).+</ul>
```

### Input :

```
<ul><li>[My search Text] is required  </li></ul>
<ul><li>[My edit Text] is not required </li></ul>
<ul><li><b>[My search Text] is mandatory </b> </li>    </ul>
<ul><li><strong>[My search Text] is so mandatory </strong> </li></ul>
```

### Desired Output :

```
<ul><li>[My search Text] is required  </li></ul>  
<ul><li><b>[My search Text] is mandatory </b> </li>    </ul>
<ul><li><strong>[My search Text] is so mandatory </strong> </li></ul>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am trying in c#. Also i dont want to make any iteration and do ismatch()

Comment: You just need to use a HTML parser with XPath like `//ul/li[contains(.,'[My search Text]')]`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Seriously... That's a problem? You won't get an upvote? That's low. How about helping people? Moving on - stribizhev is right. That's the way to go. But the problem with your regex is that the `\w+` won't match the `<`in `<li>`. If you really want to use regex, try `<ul[^>]*>\s*?<\w+?(.|\n).*(\[My search Text\]).*(.|\n).+</ul>` (minimal fix to your regex).

Comment: NO offense bro @AvinashRaj this not Facebook to get likes. thats what I thought so.

Comment: Sorry, the XPath should be a bit different. I will post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A note on your regex:

- `<ul[^>]*>` - should work OK,
- `\s*?` - no need to use a lazy quantifier
- `\w+?` - same, no need in lazy matching,
- `(.|\n)` - this makes no sense since it matches any symbol once
- `.*` - 0 or more characters other than a newline as many as possible
- `(\[My search Text\])` - a literal `[My search Text]`
- `.*(.|\n)` - same as above
- `.+` - 1 or more characters other than a newline
- `</ul>` - literal `</ul>`.

You can see that in this regex you do not really have a good multiline support. It is very inefficient due to lots of `.*` that require lots of backtracking.

I would install the [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and use the following method:

```
public List<string> HtmlAgilityPackGetTagOuterHTMLbyXpath(string html, string xpath)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hap;
    var results = new List<string>();
    Uri uriResult;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(html, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
    { // html is a URL 
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        hap = doc.Load(uriResult.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    else
    { // html is a string
        hap = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        hap.LoadHtml(html);
    }
    var nodes = hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
    if (nodes != null)
    {
       foreach (var node in nodes)
           results.Add(node.OuterHtml);
    }
    return results;
}
```

With one of these 2 XPaths that should return you 3 `<ul>` nodes:

```
//li[contains(., 'My search Text')]/ancestor::ul[1]
//ul[.//li[contains(., 'My search Text')]]
```

Like this:

```
var res = HtmlAgilityPackGetTagOuterHTMLbyXpath(s, "//li[contains(., 'My search Text')]/ancestor::ul[1]"");
```

[image]

Comment: If you need more details on how your regex performs, you can always see that at [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester) and check what it really means at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com). I do not recommend relying on `.*` or `.*?`, use negated character classes or *unrolling-the-loop* technique unless you really do not care much about speed when working with short strings. Certainly not that complex as HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:(for text inside ui)

```
 <ul>*.+(\[My search Text\]).+</ul>
```

for text inside li:

```
<ul>*.<li>*.+(\[My search Text\]).+<\/li>*.*<\/ul>
```

Comment: And did you "try" this? And what are the results?

Comment: Note that http://regexr.com supports JS regex only. The real HTML code may contain linebreaks, and your regex does not support that (hence you overescaped the pattern). You have even misused the `*` quantifier. Your regex works for the example HTML code, but it is 99% likely to fail in real-life scenario. That is why regex HTML parsing is used as home assignments in school: it is good for learning regex, but certainly is not what should be used in real life.